# Space efficient long representation

Tags: java, compression

I want to take a long value in Java, and convert it to a byte array.

However, I want the representation to be small for small values, so perhaps if the value is less than 127 then it requires only a single byte.

The encoding and decoding algorithms should be extremely efficient.

I'm sure this has been done but I can't find any example code, anyone got any pointers?

Comment: Perhaps you could take a look at UTF-8 encoding for inspiration?

Comment: Right, I'm familiar with the concept but I'd rather use an existing implementation if one exists (which I'm sure one must)

Comment: 'anyone got any pointers?' has to be a classic play on words.  Truly epic.  You might load the longs into a byte buffer and then try encoding the byte buffer as char to utf-8 strings.  Provided your bottom 7 bits align with the bottom bits of ASCII, it might work out pretty well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use stop bit encoding e.g.

```
public static void writeLong(OutputStream out, long value) throws IOException {
   while(value < 0 || value > 127) {
        out.write((byte) (0x80 | (value & 0x7F)));
        value = value >>> 7;
   }
   out.write((byte) value);
}

public static long readLong(InputStream in) throws IOException {
   int shift = 0;
   long b;
   long value = 0;
   while((b = in.read()) >= 0) {
      value += (b & 0x7f) << shift;
      shift += 7;
      if ((b & 0x80) == 0) return value;
   }
   throw new EOFException();
}
```

This is a fast form of compression, but all compression comes at a cost. (However if you are bandwidth limited it may be faster to transmit and worth the cost)

BTW: Values 0 to 127 use one `byte`. You can use the same routine for `short` and `int` values as well.

EDIT: You can still use generic compression after this and it can be smaller than not using this as well.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    long[] sequence = new long[1024];
    Random rand = new Random(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i+=2) {
        sequence[i] = (long) Math.pow(2, rand.nextDouble() * rand.nextDouble() * 61);
        // some pattern.
        sequence[i+1] = sequence[i] / 2;
    }
    testDeflator(sequence);
    testStopBit(sequence);
    testStopBitDeflator(sequence);
}

private static void testDeflator(long[] sequence) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new DeflaterOutputStream(baos));
    for (long l : sequence)
        dos.writeLong(l);
    dos.close();
    System.out.println("Deflator used " + baos.toByteArray().length);
}


private static void testStopBit(long[] sequence) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (long l : sequence)
        writeLong(baos, l);
    baos.close();
    System.out.println("Stop bit used " + baos.toByteArray().length);
}

private static void testStopBitDeflator(long[] sequence) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new DeflaterOutputStream(baos));
    for (long l : sequence)
        writeLong(dos, l);
    dos.close();
    System.out.println("Stop bit & Deflator used " + baos.toByteArray().length);
}

public static void writeLong(OutputStream out, long value) throws IOException {
    while (value < 0 || value > 127) {
        out.write((byte) (0x80 | (value & 0x7F)));
        value = value >>> 7;
    }
    out.write((byte) value);
}
```

Prints

```
Deflator used 3492
Stop bit used 2724
Stop bit & Deflator used 2615
```

What works best is highly dependant on the data you are sending. e.g. If your data is truly random, any compression technique you use will only make the data larger.

The Deflator is a stripped down version of the GZip output (minus a header and CRC32)

Comment: Hope I got all the bugs, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a `GZipOutputStream` - entropy encoding like GZip basically does exactly what you describe, just generically.

**Edit:**
Just to be sure: do you realize that a variable-length encoding that uses only 1 byte for small numbers necessarily needs to use more than 8 bytes for most large ones? Unless you know that you'll have far more small than large numbers, it could even end up increasing the overall size of your data. Whereas GZIP adapts to your actual data set and can compress data sets that are skewed in different ways.

Comment: This doesn't sound very CPU efficient though :-/

Comment: @sanity: try it out, you may be surprised. IO bandwidth hasn't kept up with CPU speeds, so if you need to process a lot of data, it can easily be faster to save it compressed and decompress it on the fly before using it.

Comment: @sanity: gzip implementations are pretty fast. Is your bottleneck CPU speed or whatever-path-these-things-are-taking bandwidth? Using a single byte for a number < 127 is pretty CPU inefficient.

Comment: I'm really sure this isn't going to be fast enough - I'm looking for something comparable in speed to Bytebuffer.putInt()

Comment: @sanity: Again: it is quite possible that compressing the data using GZip before writing it will actually be faster than writing it verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

See [Read7BitEncodedInt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.read7bitencodedint.aspx) in C#. (It's the same concept.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store `long` values with different lengths, then you'll need a delimiter, otherwise you can't decide, which byte belongs to which long value... And the delimiters will add extra bytes to the data...

If you're looking for a fast library to store long values (with 64Bit each), I'd recommend [colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/). It **is** fast.

Comment: Not true, you can do variable-length encoding without a delimiter. Just look at UTF-8 for a prominent example.

Comment: @Michael - sure, I know, every (most?) compression algorithms use variable length symbols. To be more precise: if we **don't** want to encode the values any further then just using as many bytes as needed for the value **then** we have to add delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

(I might be stating the obvious to some people ... but here goes.)

If you are doing to reduce the size `long` values in some external serialization, go ahead.

However, if you are trying to save memory in an Java program you are probably wasting your time.  The smallest representation of a `byte[]` in Java is either 2 or 3 32-bit words.  And that is for a byte array of length zero.  Add some multiple of 32 bit words to for any array length greater than zero. Then you've got to allow at least 1 32-bit word to hold the reference to the `byte[]` object.

If you add that up, it takes at least 4 words to represent any given `long` other than `0L` as a `byte[]`.

The only case where you are going to get any saving is if you are representing a number of `long` values in a single `byte[]`.  You will need at least 3 `long` values before you can possibly break even, and even then if you will lose if the values turn out to be too large on average.